# ServicePoint,HttpConnectionHttp 1.1,httppipelining, Responons,stream.close internals?

Tags: httpwebresponse, httpconnection, servicepoint

In .net framework 3.5 , http 1.1 i.e persistent connections is used and pipelining is enabled bydefault. Could you please let me know it is neccessary to close stream or connection by calling httpresponse.close or stream.close method to release a connection for another http request to the same internet resourece ? My understanding is even if httpresponse.close or stream.close is not called then too httpconnection i.e. servicepoint should be able to server another concurrent request. Please confirm.

Comment: Can you post the code your using to make the request?

Comment: WebResponse response;
try
{                
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 request.Timeout = 20000;
 response = request.GetResponse();

 request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url2);
 response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 //do something
}              
finally
{
}